# pdf file upload and stored in a folder in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am a very very beginner in java script. I want to upload a file(pdf) in java script and stored in a specific folder. i cant do it. please help.. i do it in php .But i also do it in java script.

This is my php code...

```
<form action="<?php print $PHP_SELF?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   Last Name:<br /> <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br />
   Homework:<br /> <input type="file" name="homework" value="" /><br />
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Notes" /></p>
</form>

<?php
   define ("FILEREPOSITORY","./");

   if (isset($_FILES['homework'])) {

      if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['homework']['tmp_name'])) {

         if ($_FILES['homework']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
            echo "<p>Homework must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
         } else {
            $today = date("m-d-Y");
            if (! is_dir(FILEREPOSITORY.$today)) {
               mkdir(FILEREPOSITORY.$today);
            }
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['homework']['tmp_name'], FILEREPOSITORY.$today."/"."$name.pdf");

            if ($result == 1) 
               echo "<p>File successfully uploaded.</p>";
            else 
               echo "<p>There was a problem uploading the homework.</p>";
         }
      }
   }
?>
```

I also want upload pdf file in php api.

Comment: Your PHP code is storing the file in the server. You can't do that with plain JS because it runs on the client... unless you are using Node.js on the server.

Comment: please help in code using node.js

Comment: Your server side is PHP, why Node.js here?

Comment: so how to do it in php and ajax.Please tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Jquery File upload feature. Here is a link, study the code and implement. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: this is for image upload.  i want for pdf upload

Comment: For this particular demo only images files are allowed. (by default there is no file type restriction).